# How to convert std::set to std::map with a default value in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, default-value

I have a Set of keys. I want to convert these keys into the key values of a Map. I conveniently want to set each of the matching values in the Map to the same value (1).

Here is a reproducible example.

```
set<string> keys;
keys.insert("key1");
keys.insert("key2");

map<string,int> keys_with_values;
// I want keys_with_values to equal 
     "key1": 1, "key2": 1
```

Do I have to loop through the set and insert into the map? If so, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Yes, you have to loop through the set, in some form or fashion, and as far as "what is the best way" to do this, we're back to the same problem: ask two C++ developers what is the best way to do X, and you'll get three different answers. You need to decide that yourself, based on what "best" means for you.

Comment: âny reason you want a `1` not a `0` as value?

Comment: It's for what I'm using it for. The map hold data on words, and their frequency in a post. This is for initializing the Map.

Comment: It would look exactly the same as every other loop in the C++ programming language. An initial statement, a loop condition, and a post-iteration expression. Or a C++11 range iteration. All loops in C++ look exactly the same.

Comment: *I have a Set of keys. I want to convert these keys into the key values of a Map* -- Why not start out with a map?  What's the reason for the `set`?

Comment: I'm reading in data from a csv, and it must be formatted as a set. But I eventually need these keys to be in a Map.

Comment: "The map hold data on words, and their frequency in a post. This is for initializing the Map" you do not need to initialize the map, just start counting at `0`

Comment: *and it must be formatted as a set* -- Sounds like an enforcement by your teacher or supervisor.  There is no need for a `set` for this.  Not knowing what your code looks like, I bet a cup of coffee that you could have skipped reading into a set and simply read into the map.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add a further, very c++-y way for doing that:

```cpp
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main () {
    std::set<std::string> keys;
    keys.insert("key1");
    keys.insert("key2");

    std::map<std::string,int> keys_with_values;
    std::transform(keys.cbegin(), keys.cend(), std::inserter(keys_with_values, begin(keys_with_values)), [] (const std::string &arg) { return std::make_pair(arg, 1);});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @Sam Varshavchik --here is how I implemented the loop

```
 set<string> keys;
 keys.insert("key1");
 keys.insert("key2");
 map<string,int> keys_with_values;
 for(auto key : keys) {
     keys_with_values[key] = 1;
 }
 cout << keys_with_values["key1"]; // 1
```

Comment: In honoring Sam's C++ diversitee comment you could also do `keys_with_values.insert({ key, 1})` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using lambdas:

```
for_each(keys.begin(), keys.end(), [&](auto key)
{
    keys_with_values.insert({ key, 1});
});
```

And for completeness sake, here's one using iterators:

```
set<string>::iterator it = keys.begin();
while (it != keys.end())
{
    keys_with_values.insert({ *it, 1});
    it++;
}
```